# Flutter build fails

Tags: flutter

Yesterday, the application was launched on the emulator and the phone.

But today nothing works, nothing has been done and has not changed.
Help me please!

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...


Compiler message: 
lib/screens/reminder/alarm.dart:98:16: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AndroidNotificationSound'.
 - 'AndroidNotificationSound' is from 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_specifics/android/notification_sound.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-1.4.3/lib/src/platform_specifics/android/notification_sound.dart').
        sound: 'sd',
               ^
lib/screens/stories.dart:56:29: Error: Method not found: 'StoryItem.pageGif'.
        items.add(StoryItem.pageGif(
                            ^^^^^^^
lib/screens/stories.dart:68:33: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
        items.add(StoryItem.text(
                                ^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/story_view-0.12.3/lib/widgets/story_view.dart:52:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static StoryItem text({
                   ^^^^
lib/screens/stories.dart:77:22: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
          ? StoryView(
                     ^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/story_view-0.12.3/lib/widgets/story_view.dart:397:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  StoryView({
  ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.14.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:92:3: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
  PictureStream();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.14.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter extends Diagnosticable {
               ^

Compiler message:
lib/screens/reminder/alarm.dart:98:16: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AndroidNotificationSound'.
 - 'AndroidNotificationSound' is from 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_specifics/android/notification_sound.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-1.4.3/lib/src/platform_specifics/android/notification_sound.dart').
        sound: 'sd',
               ^
lib/screens/stories.dart:56:29: Error: Method not found: 'StoryItem.pageGif'.
        items.add(StoryItem.pageGif(
                            ^^^^^^^
lib/screens/stories.dart:68:33: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
        items.add(StoryItem.text(
                                ^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/story_view-0.12.3/lib/widgets/story_view.dart:52:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static StoryItem text({
                   ^^^^
lib/screens/stories.dart:77:22: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
          ? StoryView(
                     ^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/story_view-0.12.3/lib/widgets/story_view.dart:397:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  StoryView({
  ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.14.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:92:3: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
  PictureStream();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.14.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter extends Diagnosticable {
               ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Check lines with errors: `lib/screens/reminder/alarm.dart:98:16`, `lib/screens/stories.dart:56:29`, etc

Comment: I agrre with @Pavel, check lines with error and also try flutter clean and Invalidate Caches/Restart then try to build again if it works and you really do not any changes in anywhere.

Comment: I got this after running `flutter pub upgrade` by mistake.  I reinstalled the latest stable version of flutter and deleted the `.packages` file, then rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

try "flutter clean" command and then re-run your application

Comment: Would it be possible to  share the code for the file alarm.dart? This will enable us to help you better

Comment: scheduledalarm(int id, var timeofalarm) async {
    var scheduledNotificationDateTime =
        Time(timeofalarm.hour, timeofalarm.minute);
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your  channel name', 'your  channel description',
        sound: 'sd',
        autoCancel: true,
        playSound: true,
        color: primaryColor,
        importance: Importance.Max,
        priority: Priority.High);
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        new IOSNotificationDetails(sound: "sd.aiff", presentSound: true);

Comment: some problem in the line
  sound: 'sd',

Comment: Help me please!

Comment: Try assigning RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('sd'), to your sound parameter instead of passing the string 'sd' directly

Comment: Can I see your code after the change I proposed please?

Comment: And where it can be assigned, I poorly understand your recommendations for 'sd'

Comment: I am not recommending anything. I am just saying that you cannot assign "sd" which I don't really understand what it stands for to the variable sound. parameter sound does not except string and that is why I suggested you use RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound and give it the path to your sound file (assuming your sound file name is "sd")